# Не могу запустить Keycloak в Docker

Tags: docker, keycloak

Пробую запустить Keycloak в Docker.
Подскажите почему у меня при запуске

```
docker-compose up -d
```

процесс keycloak висит в статусе exited
при этом у postgres статус running
Пробую посмотреть логи, там только

```
opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak-add-user.json (Is a directory)
```

Зайти в контейнер я не могу, т.к. он не существует

вот сам docker-compose

```html
version: "3.8"

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: library/postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak_db
      DB_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres}
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin_password
    ports:
      - "8484:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - "postgres:postgres"
```

Код взял из этой статьи
[Подключение Keycloak к Spring Boot приложению](https://habr.com/ru/company/reksoft/blog/552346/)

Comment: exited это означает что процесс в контейнере завершился (ошибка, просто завершил свою работу), посмотрите на логи контейнера, возможно там есть описание причины (ошибки) через docker compose logs или docker logs <имя контейнера>

Comment: Пробовал, я в вопросе привел, что мне выдает лог